# regex to highlight new line characters in the beginning and end

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out how to write a simple regex that would highlight newline characters only if they appear at the beginning or end of some data while preserving the newline.

In the below example, line 1 and line 14 both are new lines. Those are the only two lines I am trying to highlight as they appear at the beginning and end of the data.

```py
import regex as re
from colorama import Fore, Back

def red(s):
    return Back.RED + s + Back.RESET

with open('/tmp/1.py', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

print(
    re.sub(r'(^\n|\n$)', red(r'\1'), data)
)
```

In the open expression, data is the same content as the example posted above.

In the above example, this is the result I am getting:

[image]

As one can see, the red highlight is missing on line 1 and is spanning all the way in line 14. What I would like is for the color to appear only once per new line character.

Comment: `^` and `$` match start/end of line. It doesn't match the start/end of the whole content.

Comment: That is probably related to the way terminal does its job, see [this issue](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/170)

Comment: Don't know why but it works when you have 2 linefeeds at the beginning of the script.

Comment: When I run your code, whether I use `(^\n|\n$)` or `(\A\n|\n\Z)`, I get `"\x1b[41m\n\x1b[49"` at the beginning and end. So I can't duplicate your problem. On my Windows 10 platform, neither results in a red line, but that's a different issue. When I run it on Linux, again I see no red until the output is at the bottom of the screen and then the first red line appears mysteriously after the `import` statement. Perhaps there is just something wrong with the method of creating a red line around a newline character.

Comment: Just a side comment: your replacement text, `red(r'\1')`, is only being evaluated once for the very first match with whatever `\1` happens to be and that value will be used for subsequent replacements. It works in your case because in your case every match is the same, namely `\n`, and you therefore can use the same substitution. But in general this is the wrong way to do it. Better would be: `lambda m: red(m[1])` to guarantee that `red` gets called for each match.

Comment: Yes you are right @Booboo. I also cannot explain why on first run, the red lines doesnt show up, but it does with a second run. The the side comment was really helpful! Didnt think about it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all the comments, and suggestions, and combining a subset of them all, I finally have a working version. For anyone that is interested:

One issue I cannot overcome without writing an os specific check is how an extra new line being added for windows.

A couple of highlights that were picked up:

- cannot color a `\n`. So replace that with a space and newline.
- have not tested this, but by getting rid of the group replacement, it may be possible to apply this to bytes also.
- Windows supported can be attained with `init` in colorama

```py
import regex as re
from colorama import Back, init

init() # for windows

def red(s):
    return Back.RED + s + Back.RESET

with open('/tmp/1.py', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

fist_line = re.sub('\A\n', red(' ')+'\n', data)
last_line = re.sub('\n\Z', '\n'+red(' '), fist_line)
print(last_line)
```

### OSX/Linux

[image]

### Windows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use your regex, but without the "multiline" flag. Than it will see the whole string as one and you will actually match your desired output.

```
^\n|\n$
```

Here you can see that there are two matches. And if you delete new lines in front or in the end, the matches will disapear. The multilene flag is set or disabled at the end of the regex line. You could do that in your language too.

https://regex101.com/r/pSRHPU/2

Comment: This seems identical to my regex without the grouping. I am grouping so that I can replace the capture group with itself.

Comment: it is identical. My main proposal is -keep regex,  dont use the multiline flag.

Comment: Ah. Yes, I am not using Multiline. I tried with a lookahead also, but that didnt take

Answer (score -1):

I found a way that seems to allow you to match the start/end of the whole string. See the "Permanent Start of String and End of String Anchors" part from https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

> `\A` only ever matches at the start of the string. Likewise, `\Z` only ever matches at the end of the string.

I created a demo here https://regex101.com/r/n2DAWh/1

Regex is: `(\A\n|\n\Z)`

Comment: I definetly learned something from your answer! But, it doesnt fully solve the need. if you run the code, you notice that it is not highlighting one one, but the end of line 2 instead.